# can't run "seaborn" in Jupyter Noterbook (python 2.7)

Tags: seaborn

windows 10, default path of python 2.7
[I try to install with using pip install seaborn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2SS3.png)

[Another method mentioned in other questions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s673q.png)

Comment: Don't post links, write what you did in your question.

Answer (score 0):

owing to reputation, I can't comment under other answers.
I use 
conda install seaborn
in command
and then import in jupyter notebook
it worked！